# equals() using strings return true while the two variable are not

Tags: java, android, xml, equals

I have a weird issue on my android app. When the above method is ran and `answer_str = "When the activity is destroyed"` and `questCHoiceStr = "When the user leave the activity."`. But the if condition returns true that's really strange!

```
private QuestionChoice getSelectedQuestionChoice()
{
    int radioButtonID = radioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)radioButtonGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
    if (radioButton != null)
    {
        String answer_str = radioButton.getText().toString();
        for (int i = 0; i < map.get(current_question).size(); i++)
        {
            List<QuestionChoice> questionChoiceList = map.get(current_question);
            QuestionChoice questionChoice = questionChoiceList.get(i);
            String questCHoiceStr = questionChoice.choice;
            if (questCHoiceStr.equals(answer_str));
            {
                return map.get(current_question).get(i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    else
    return null;
}
```

I tried to add `trim()` but nothing changed...
The string used in my program are string from a xml file (maybe it has something do do with this).
DO you have any idea what can cause that?
thx

Comment: come on who puts `;` after `if(condition)`.

Comment: Maybe someone who made a mistake?

Comment: yeppp ...try to avoid this in future @Antoine D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you added `;`, that closed right away there.

```
if (questCHoiceStr.equals(answer_str)); <--
```

Your if is not really working as you closed it right away.

should be

```
if (questCHoiceStr.equals(answer_str))
```

Your current code is equals to

```
if (questCHoiceStr.equals(answer_str)){

}
{
     return map.get(current_question).get(i);
}
```

*Just to avoid these kind of issues, I force my friends to use `{}` always :*

Comment: Thank you very much :P I didn't noticed that semicolon! It works like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks for those precisions. I accepted your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the semi colon on the if statement. The semicolon marks the end of the if statement so the next block between braces {} is just code that will always be run.

```
if (questCHoiceStr.equals(answer_str))
{
    return map.get(current_question).get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private QuestionChoice getSelectedQuestionChoice()
    {
        int radioButtonID = radioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)radioButtonGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
        if (radioButton != null)
        {
            String answer_str = radioButton.getText().toString();
            for (int i = 0; i < map.get(current_question).size(); i++)
            {
                List<QuestionChoice> questionChoiceList = map.get(current_question);
                QuestionChoice questionChoice = questionChoiceList.get(i);
                String questCHoiceStr = questionChoice.choice;
                **if (questCHoiceStr.equals(answer_str))**
                {
                    return map.get(current_question).get(i);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        else
        return null;
    }
```